# Read data from grid

Tags: javascript

can you please tell me where is the error

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
     var $countryGrid = $(".countries").grid();
     var $cityGrid = $(".cities").grid();
     $countryGrid.on("rowClick",function(event, $row, rowData) {
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     var code = rowData.Code;
     console.log(x);
     $cityGrid.grid("load",{
     action: "world-ajax.php?type=city&country=" +code 
    });
    });
   </script>
```

x value is null. But if wrie console.log(rowData) it's show me full object. Object {serial: "6", date: "2014-10-01"} .now is there any way to select this serial and pass this action parameter

Comment: Can you please change your question's tag `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pass along the serial, cant you just do it like so?:

```
var serial = rowData.serial;
action : "somescript.php?serial=" + serial;
```

Comment: You are simply great. it's work and for this i spend more then 10 hours.